# JavaFX (controlsfx-8.20.8) tabbed pane view displaying partially

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, controlsfx

I was building an application using "JavaFx" (controlsfx-8.0.6) and it was working fine with **Windows** but in **Macintosh** and **Linux** environment the message box that I was using, didn't work.

So I moved to `controlsfx-8.20.8`. Which fixed my message box loading problem but the UI that has tabbed pane become partial view. I tried several things to make it right at last I found that if I comment the `setStage(Stage stage, Object[] obj)` method the UI work fine but I want to use that method in-order to do my other operations in UI , if any one know how to resolve this problem please help me.

All the UI designed from "JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your UI `size` in the `setStage` you can achieve your goal.

Sample code given below:

```
public void setStage(Stage stage, Object[] obj) {
   this.stage = stage;
   stage.setHeight(611.0);
   stage.setWidth(920.0);
}
```

Comment: If it was helpful and correct, then please choose it as the correct answer!